# javascript regex replace not working in apache camel

Tags: javascript, apache-camel, dsl

I am using apache camel 2.11 and camel-script 2.2 for javascript support with spring DSL.

I wanted to do a regex replace with groups, but that does not seem to work in camel.

Eg :- in a transform, the following works

```
<javaScript>request.body.toString().replace("Y","X")</javaScript>
```

i.e Change YZ to XZ

But the following does not :-

```
<javaScript>request.body.toString().replace("/(Y)(.*)$/g","\$1")</javaScript>
```

ie. Change YZXXX to Y

I have tested the regex itself at https://regex101.com/, so I don't believe its a syntax issue in the regex itself

Now it may be possible that camel-script offers only partial javascript support. but I am not sure if that is the case. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue :-)

The issue is :- I was assuming that Camel javascript can use javascript functions... when in fact it calls java functions.

Changing the code to java syntax ( calling replaceAll() function with java syntax for regex) resolved the issue.

Comment: [Camel supports JavaScript](http://camel.apache.org/javascript.html) and the code inside the `<javaScript>` element actually *is* JS, as well. So I'm a bit doubtful that your solution actually is correct.

Comment: Well it does work for me, and javascript does allow calling java functions.. so it could be a problem with the way I called the javascript functions, or a limitation when javascript is used with Spring DSL  perhaps ?

In any case, I will do some further test by trying to call outer simple Native javascript functions to see if those work..

Comment: Ok, it could be due to the request.body object being a java object rather than a javascript object...

Comment: I don't know enough about the internals of Spring/Camel to be sure about that. It would be very odd if JS and Java would co-exist in the same source code snippet, though, inside a `<javaScript>` element no less. Makes no sense if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a *regex*, not a string looks like a regex. Compare:

Wrong:

```
request.body.toString().replace("/(Y)(.*)$/g","\$1")
```

Correct:

```
request.body.toString().replace(/(Y)(.*)$/g, "\$1")
```

---

That being said, the backslash in your replace pattern is superfluous. `"$1"` would be correct.

Comment: Nope.. I tried that as well before posting .. but thanks !

Comment: You might have tried this before, but as far as JS goes, the first line of code does not work, the second one does.